# Design pattern for handling frequent logic changes in extending classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a processor class - `AbstractProcessor` and multiple concrete classes (that extend this base class) which get called in order of the business logic.

```
public Abstract class AbstractProcessor {
   public void doProcess(){}
}
```

The logic in my concrete classes keeps on changing depending on the business requirements. This leads to a change in the corresponding test classes and seems to be a tightly coupled approach.

Is there a better way to design such classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java Interfaces and override different versions of the implementation based on your need. You can call the specific implementation based on your/client's need.

```
Example:
Interface A{
    void showName();
}

class X implements A{
    void showName(){
        System.out.print("my name is X");
    }
}

class Y implements A{
    void showName(){
        System.out.print("my name is Y");
    }
}
```

Now, based on your/client's need you can instantiate specific class which fulfills your requirement. You can have N number of implementations for N number of clients.

```
class Test{

    public static void main (String [] a){
        /* For client X */
        A a1 = new X();
        a1.showName();

        /* For client Y */
        A a2 = new Y();
        a2.showName();
    }
}
```

P.S. Please mind the code, I have written it directly in editor

Comment: Thanks Ady, but my problem was. Y gets called after X, and the logic of y.showName() keeps on changing. How do I deal with it better.

Comment: Even though I have shown the calls to showName one after another, do not call them in single method. You instantiate any one of them (X or Y) based on the client for which you are making this application.

Example:
You want to give this app to client X the in main method do 'new X()' and for client Y do 'new Y()'

Comment: Is the `AbstractProcessor` actually an abstract class (has some logic and some abstract methods)?  From your example it looks like it should be a simple interface as there is no logic.